# How do I compare string and boolean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, boolean-logic, boolean

I got the Json `"false"` from server. I respond as `bool` but it's Json so it's in browser type is `String` instead of `bool`.

So if I run `(!data)` whenever I want to check `"false" == false` then they not worked.

So how can I parse `bool` from `String` in JavaScript then?

`"true" == true` and `"false" == false`. Then the code `(!data)` can check what it is [`true` and `false`]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would just explicitly check for the string `"true"`.

```
let data = value === "true";
```

Otherwise you could use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to a native JavaScript value, but it's a lot of overhead if you know it's only the strings `"true"` or `"false"` you will receive.

Comment: JSON.parse() will decode the server boolean to javascript boolean, so you can call (!myJSONObject.myBool) it's more recomended than the eval.  json.org

Comment: This is really overkill.  It is at least as efficient to simply test the string value against "true".  Besides being perfectly sufficient for his needs, it's also universally portable.

Comment: @chomp It does answer the question *How can I parse bool from string in JavaScript?* I would simply check for the string `'false'`, however.

Comment: At this point it becomes a petty argument, since it is no more valid to suggest that "banana" is true than it is to suggest that "banana" is false. :)

Comment: this thing i found later because project not have this one [json.js]. i use jQuery.parseJSON(). thanks

Answer (score 21):

> - *If one of the operands is a boolean, convert the boolean operand to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.*
> - *When comparing a number to a string, try to convert the string to a numeric value.*
>
> from [MDN *Equality Operators* page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality#description)

Examples:

```
true == "true";   // 1 == NaN → false
true == "1";      // 1 == 1   → true
false == "false"; // 0 == NaN → false
false == "";      // 0 == 0   → true
false == "0";     // 0 == 0   → true
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var data = true;
data === "true" //false
String(data) === "true" //true
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try expression data == "true"

Tests:

data = "false" -- value will be false

date = "true" -- value will be true

Also, fix your JSON. JSON can handle booleans just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If its just a json "false"/"true", you can use,

```
if(! eval(data)){
    // Case when false
}
```

It would be more cleaner, if you restrict the code to accept only JSON data from server, and always jsonParse or eval it to JS object (*something like jquery getJSON does. It accepts only JSON responses and parse it to object before passing to callback function*).

That way you'll not only get boolean as boolean-from-server, but it will retain all other datatypes as well, and you can then go for routine expressions statements rather than special ones.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at how the JSON data is being generated. You can definitely have a normal JS boolean false in JSON.

{ "value1" : false, "value2" : true }

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.revalue= function(){
  if(/^(true|false|null|undefined|NaN)$/i.test(this)) return eval(this);
  if(parseFloat(this)+''== this) return parseFloat(this);
  return this;
}
```

From: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147389

Actually, you just need the first "if" statement from the function -- tests to find true or false in the code and the `eval`s it, turning it into the boolean value

Comment: Adding functions to a base class (such as String) tends to raise maintainability and clarity issues.

Comment: While clever - and maybe I'm just a stickler for type safety - I would never in a million years encourage anyone to use this code for any practical purpose, ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data+''=='true'){
    alert('true');
}
```

Convert boolean to string by appending with blank string. and then compare with Stringobject.