# JavaScript seems to evaluate an invalid result when comparing two values

Tags: javascript

If I write the following code:

```
" \t\r\n" == 0
```

JavaScript will return `true`. However, if I manually convert both values to boolean, then:

```
!!" \t\r\n" // returns true
!!0 // returns false
```

That's mean JavaScript says that `true == false` in the first expression, but the opposite if I compare values converted to boolean, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Please note that I don't write `!!"0"` but `!!0` instead - big difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: this does not answer my question. I don't use === operator here

Comment: @BassT JavaScript should convert both values to boolean if I use == and this is not working as shown above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do both if('0'==false) and if('0') evaluate to true in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450750/why-do-both-if0-false-and-if0-evaluate-to-true-in-javascript)

Comment: *"JavaScript should convert both values to boolean if I use =="* -- that's just not true.

Comment: What makes you think javascript should convert both values to boolean ?

Comment: @Juhana the answer provided by BassT says that "The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions." which means it convert both values to boolean

Comment: Noooo, it means it converts both values to ***the same type***, not boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison

```
" \t\r\n" == 0
```

is true because the specification for the language says it should be true.

Lets start with the algorithm for [Abstract Equality Comparison](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.html#sec-11.9.3) (`x == y`)

> If Type(`x`) is *String* and Type(`y`) is *Number*, return the result of the
>   comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

See what it says there, if the first one is a string, which it is, and the second one is a number, which it is, convert the first one to a number based on the `ToNumber()` operation.

So what's the `ToNumber()` operation, [here it is in the spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.html#sec-9.3)

> ToNumber applied to Strings applies the following grammar to the input
>   String.
>   If the grammar cannot interpret the String as an expansion of
>   StringNumericLiteral, then the result of ToNumber is NaN.

The entire chapter on how different strings are converted with `ToNumber` is pretty complicated, but a little further down in the spec is says

> The **MV** of `StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty]` is `0`.
>   The **MV** of `StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace` is `0`.

*(MV = Mathematical Value)*

So any string that is empty, or just contain whitespace, is converted to `0`.

Lets just try and coerce the string ourselves

```
console.log( +" \t\r\n" ); // gives the number 0
```

So a string containing a whitespace, a tab, and a newline, is converted to `0`.

So, converting the string `" \t\r\n"` with the internal `ToNumber()` operation gives the browser `0`, so naturally `0 == 0` is `true`, and that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're using equality and not strict equality to compare two values.

When using `==` (equality) values will be coerced. This won't happen when using `===` (strict equality).

```
" \t\r\n" == 0 // returns true, these values are 'falsy', which are coerced to false 

" \t\r\n" === 0 // returns false
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for reference.