# Javascript AND OR operators and parentheses

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, operators

Having issues correctly triggering code in an if and or statement. I want the code in the statement to run when the defholdid var is equal to "cb_SR" AND if ANY of these variables are true: altRighttargets, inRightTargets, safetyRightTargets. I have checked each variable on their own and they all receive the values I expect. Here's the statement:

```
 if (defholdid === "cb_SR" && (altRightTargets === true || inRightTargets === true || safetyRightTargets === true)) {
        //code I want to trigger
};
```

I checked the statement with each individual expression, and I can get the code to trigger, so I think I'm incorrectly writing the statement.

Thanks,

Comment: It looks fine here. Can you make a [MCVE] illustrating the problem?

Comment: If the `xxxTargets` variables always contain boolean values, you don't need to write `=== true`. Just write `(altRightTargets || inRightTargets || safetyRightTargets)`

Comment: @Barmar, that worked for me, so thank you! But I'm not sure why?

Comment: that shouldn't have made a difference, unless the variables didn't really contain boolean. Maybe they contained strings?

Comment: @Barmar I went through my code and indeed one of the variables was set to 'true' with quotes rather than true boolean value. I fixed it, and now both methods (including my original syntax) work. It "worked" because I'm guessing it ignored "safetyRightTargets" (the variable incorrectly set to string)? Any rate, thanks for the help, wouldn't have found the issue without your comment and probably would've caused me a real headache down the road!

Comment: I'll post an answer that explains in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the variables you're comparing with `true` actually hold boolean values, not strings `"true"` or `"false"`. If they contain these strings, the comparison with `true` will always be false. In the context of your OR grouping, that variable is effectively ignored.

The strict equality operator `===` will always be false for values of different types. But even if you change to the loose equality operator `==`, `true == "true"` will be false. When comparing a boolean with another type, the boolean is converted to `0` or `1` first, and then this is compared with the other value (with additional type juggling possible). So `true == "1"` is true because `1 == "1"`, but `true == "true"` is false because `1 == "true"` is false. As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581884/1491895), we have the following cases of comparing a boolean with a string:

```
true == "true"; //false
true == "1"; //true
false == "false"; //false
false == ""; //true
false == "0"; //true
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, makes sense to me now.